# comparing two data on aspx memo with the data it contains a ";"

Tags: c#

I enter the data in 2 aspx memo like this :

```
aspxmemo1 = php;visual basic;c#

aspxmemo2 = visual basic;javascript
```

question :
how to check if any data was similar between the 2 aspxmemo that it will show an error message.

Note:
In the above examples, the same data is: "Visual Basic".

Comment: I don't know about aspx memo, but if you have those as string, you can user string.Split to get arrays and check them by using LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your memo's are strings: if you split the strings on ';', you have nice collections, which are far more easy to operate on for example with Linq.

```
var aspxmemo1 = "php;visual basic;c#";

var aspxmemo2 = "visual basic;javascript";

var collection1 = aspxmemo1.Split(';');
var collection2 = aspxmemo2.Split(';');

if (collection1.Intersect(collection2).Any())
{
      //Do Something
}

//Or iterate over the duplicate memo's (you get the point)
 foreach(var item in collection1.Intersect(collection2))
 {
       Console.WriteLine(item + " occured in both collections!");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
            string aspxmemo1 = "php;visual basic;c#";
            string aspxmemo2 = "visual basic;javascript";
            string copies ="";
            string[] group1 = aspxmemo1.Split(';');
            string[] group2 = aspxmemo2.Split(';');
            foreach (string x in group1)
            {
                if (group2.Contains<string>(x))
                {
                    copies += x + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show(copies);
```

Comment: Any reason for not using Enumerable.Intersect() ?

Comment: Honestly? I did not know that.
It is possible that your answer is better, more professional.
However, both methods work.